# Largest "separation" of patterns for Delphi regex?

Tags: regex, delphi

#### Update

As `Graymatter` has observed, regex fails to match when there are at least 2 extra line breaks before the second target. That is to say, changing the concatenation loop to "for I := 0 to 1" will make the regex-match fail.

---

As shown in the code below, without the concatenation, the program can get the two values using regex. However, with the concatenation, the program cannot get the two values.

Could you help to comment on the reason and the workaround ?

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  // www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html
  // http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/TPerlRegEx.zip
  PerlRegEx,
  SysUtils;

procedure Test;
var
  Content: UTF8String;
  Regex: TPerlRegEx;
  GroupIndex: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Regex := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  Regex.Regex := 'Value1 =\s*(?P<Value1>\d+)\s*.*\s*Value2 =\s*(?P<Value2>\d*\.\d*)';

  Content := '';
  for I := 0 to 10000000 do
  begin
    // Uncomment here to see effect
    // Content := Content + 'junkjunkjunkjunkjunk' + sLineBreak;
  end;

  Regex.Subject := 'junkjunkjunkjunkjunk' +
    sLineBreak + ' Value1 = 1' +
    sLineBreak + 'junkjunkjunkjunkjunk' + Content +
    sLineBreak + ' Value2 = 1.23456789' +
    sLineBreak + 'junkjunkjunkjunkjunk';

  if Regex.Match then
  begin
    GroupIndex := Regex.NamedGroup('Value1');
    Writeln(Regex.Groups[GroupIndex]);
    GroupIndex := Regex.NamedGroup('Value2');
    Writeln(Regex.Groups[GroupIndex]);
  end
  else
  begin
    Writeln('No match');
  end;
  Regex.Free;
end;

begin
  Test;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: @Graymatter Without the super-long concatenation, the subject string still contains sLineBreak.

Comment: Ok, I tested again now. It is the line breaks that's making it fail. When there are at least 2 extra line breaks before then it fails. so changing your loop to for "I := 0 to 1" will make it fail. "0 to 0" doesn't make it fail.

Comment: @Graymatter Thank you for your helpful observation ! Could you help to comment on possible workaround ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help any more. I don't know enough about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line works.

```
  Regex.Options := [preSingleLine];
```

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/RegularExpressionsCore.TPerlRegExOptions):

`preSingleLine`

> Normally, dot (.) matches anything but a newline (\n). With preSingleLine, dot (.) will match anything, including newlines. This allows a multiline string to be regarded as a single entity. Equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. Note that preMultiLine and preSingleLine can be used together.

When there is only one line break before the second target, the regex can match even without preSingleline. The reason is because \s can match line return.